# PHP: How can I retain and use link parameters

Tags: php, forms

I am currently trying to work out a basic referral form. The process is as follows:

1. The referrer will use a form to send an email to their friends. (Example: http://www.graphicgoldfish.com/refer.html) As you can see, the form requires their Username and their IGN (in-game name). This is very important.
2. A link is generated using the referrer's information as the parameters. The parameters will be used to reward the referrer once the friend has completed the second form. (Example: http://www.graphicgoldfish.com/referral.html?ref_username=LRRoberts0122&ref_ign=DerpyGoldfish)
3. When that link is clicked, it opens up a second form where the friend can input their information. *My problem is, that when the friend submits the form, the parameters from the original URL do not get passed.*

How am I able to keep those parameters after the submission?

My PHP:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['ref_username'];
echo $_GET['ref_ign'];

if (isset($_GET['ref_username'])) {
$r_username = $_GET['ref_username'];
}

if (isset($_GET['ref_ign'])) {
    $r_ign = $_GET['ref_ign'];
}
```

None of this seems to be doing what I want. My guess is that it doesn't exist, because if I run the PHP and manually add the parameters, it works. I'm just not sure how to go about doing this automagically.

**EDIT:** The parameters are being passed into an HTML file from the link that was generated. The friend needs to fill out a form. How can I get the values that were passed in the parameters to the HTML file, and concatenate them to the action (where it submits to a PHP file)?

This is not working for me.

```
<form action="http://www.graphicgoldfish.com/php/referral.php?ref_username=<?php echo $ref_username ?>&ref_ign=<?php echo $ref_ign?>" method="POST">
```

Comment: You can put your get variables into your form's action, e.g. `<form action="somefile.php?get_variables=here" method="post">`

Comment: option 1. put them in the form (hidden elements or action) 2. use a session

Answer (score 1):

First off...in your generator.php form.  You are using **POST** not **GET**

So you should retrive your variables as such.

```
if (isset($_POST['ref_username'])) {
  $r_username = $_POST['ref_username'];
}

if (isset($_POST['ref_ign'])) {
   $r_ign = $_POST['ref_ign'];
}
```

Secondly when you generate that link with the paramters in it.  You are passing the parameters to an **html** file.

```
 http://www.graphicgoldfish.com/referral.html?ref_username=LRRoberts0122&ref_ign=DerpyGoldfish
```

You need to pass them to a **php** file for this to work...

```
http://www.graphicgoldfish.com/referral.php?ref_username=LRRoberts0122&ref_ign=DerpyGoldfish
```

Comment: Does this mean I have to put my html file in a PHP file? Because this is going to be for a website that is using Enjin. And I don't have access to the actual file like that. :( Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: file extensions don't always match file type.

Comment: I have to make the url go to a specific html page. Is it possible to embed PHP to grab the variables and then send them when the second form is submitted?

Comment: if the 'html' page does not parse php, then no.

Comment: Okay, so yes. The parameters are being passed into an HTML file. The friend needs to fill out a form. How can I get the values that were passed in the parameters to the HTML file, and concatenate them to the action (where it submits to a PHP file)?